# Facing "RangeError: Not enough bytes available." When i try to get values from Hive db

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, adapter

I have an application that send a type to a db in Hive and in my adapter I have the methods read and write to all my variables. The problem is with this variable:

```
@HiveField(5)
String? imoString;
```

This is the line responsible to read the variable in adapter:

```
model.imoString = reader.readString();
```

and this one is to write:

```
writer.writeString(model.imoString ?? "");
```

I am 100% sure that I'm saving the variable correctly (with the type string and the value as the value the user wrote in screen) because I can print it in write method. But when I reload the app and the method get from db is called I face this error pointing to the line `model.imoString = reader.readString();`:

```
Unhandled Exception: RangeError: Not enough bytes available.
```

What can I do?

I tried to read with reader.read but it didnt work as well
Obs: the variables are in the right sequence in read and write methods

**EDIT**
I figured out that if I comment the first item of this adapter in both read and write it works.. this first element is another model with its own adapter (it has a lot of variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing all the varibles both in read and write to just `read()` and `write()` without the type

Comment: For some reason this worked !

Comment: Had the same problem and this worked. I have absolutely no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're calling readString/readStringList/etc on an object that was stored with less data (e.g. an older version of your hive model).

To fix this, you'll need to check for the available bytes when reading the older hive model with a new adapter that is made for reading your newer hive model.

Here's an example:

Hive model:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import '../utils/observation_utils.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class LocalObservation extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0, defaultValue: "")
  String uid;

  @HiveField(1, defaultValue: "")
  String observerUid;

  @HiveField(2, defaultValue: 0.0)
  double altitudeInMeters;

  @HiveField(3, defaultValue: 0.0)
  double longitude;

  @HiveField(4, defaultValue: 0.0)
  double latitude;

  @HiveField(5, defaultValue: "")
  String name;

  @HiveField(6, defaultValue: "")
  String location;

  @HiveField(7, defaultValue: "")
  String date;

  @HiveField(8, defaultValue: <String>[])
  List<String> signs;

  @HiveField(9, defaultValue: "")
  String pikasDetected;

  @HiveField(10, defaultValue: "")
  String distanceToClosestPika;

  @HiveField(11, defaultValue: "")
  String searchDuration;

  @HiveField(12, defaultValue: "")
  String talusArea;

  @HiveField(13, defaultValue: "")
  String temperature;

  @HiveField(14, defaultValue: "")
  String skies;

  @HiveField(15, defaultValue: "")
  String wind;

  @HiveField(16, defaultValue: <String>[])
  List<String> otherAnimalsPresent;

  @HiveField(17, defaultValue: "")
  String siteHistory;

  @HiveField(18, defaultValue: "")
  String comments;

  @HiveField(19, defaultValue: <String>[])
  List<String> imageUrls;

  @HiveField(20, defaultValue: <String>[])
  List<String> audioUrls;

  // New field
  @HiveField(21, defaultValue: "")
  String species;

  // New field
  @HiveField(22, defaultValue: <String>[])
  List<String> sharedWithProjects;

  // New field    
  @HiveField(23, defaultValue: <String>[])
  List<String> notSharedWithProjects;
 
  // New field
  @HiveField(24, defaultValue: "")
  String dateUpdatedInGoogleSheets;

  LocalObservation(
    {
      this.uid = "",
      this.observerUid = "",
      this.name = "",
      this.location = "",
      this.date = "",
      this.altitudeInMeters = 0.0,
      this.latitude = 0.0,
      this.longitude = 0.0,
      this.species = SPECIES_DEFAULT,
      this.signs = const <String>[],
      this.pikasDetected = "",
      this.distanceToClosestPika = "",
      this.searchDuration = "",
      this.talusArea = "",
      this.temperature = "",
      this.skies = "",
      this.wind = "",
      this.siteHistory = "",
      this.comments = "",
      this.imageUrls = const <String>[],
      this.audioUrls = const <String>[],
      this.otherAnimalsPresent = const <String>[],
      this.sharedWithProjects = const <String>[],
      this.notSharedWithProjects = const <String>[],
      this.dateUpdatedInGoogleSheets = ""
    }
  );
}
```

Adapter

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'local_observation.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

// DO NOT CHANGE THE READ OR WRITE ORDER BETWEEN ADAPTER VERSIONS!
// Calling "write" will save data in one block, in the 
// linear order in which it is called. Calling "read" pulls the data 
// from that one block until there are no more bytes available. 

// So, if you called writeString(someString) and then 
// writeString(someOtherString), you'll be storing "someStringSomeOtherString".
// Then, if you call someOtherString = readString, someString = readString,
// it will return someString then someOtherString since that's the 
// the order of strings saved to the block.

// In short, the adapter's write/read order needs to remain consistent between
// adapter versions, and need to have same read order as write order.
// When additional fields are added to the hive model, add the writes/reads
// for each new field after the old writes/reads.

// Additionally, when the number of bytes written with a previous adapter are less 
// than bytes written with a new adapter, because you added fields to the
// hive model, then the new adapter will try to continue reading bytes
// on the old model stored in db, and that model doesn't have any more.
// Consequently, hive will throw "not enough bytes" error because there are no more bytes to read.

class LocalObservationAdapter extends TypeAdapter<LocalObservation> {

  @override
  int get typeId => 0;

  @override
  read(BinaryReader reader) {
    // Retrieve the observation data consistent across all versions of LocalObservation
    var localObservation = LocalObservation(
        uid: reader.readString(),
        observerUid: reader.readString(),
        altitudeInMeters: reader.readDouble(),
        longitude: reader.readDouble(),
        latitude: reader.readDouble(),
        name: reader.readString(),
        location: reader.readString(),
        date: reader.readString(),
        signs: reader.readStringList(),
        pikasDetected: reader.readString(),
        distanceToClosestPika: reader.readString(),
        searchDuration: reader.readString(),
        talusArea: reader.readString(),
        temperature: reader.readString(),
        skies: reader.readString(),
        wind: reader.readString(),
        otherAnimalsPresent: reader.readStringList(),
        siteHistory: reader.readString(),
        comments: reader.readString(),
        imageUrls: reader.readStringList(),
        audioUrls: reader.readStringList(),
    );

    // If the observation is older, there won't be any more bytes to read.
    // Trying to do so will throw the error "Not enough bytes available"
    if (reader.availableBytes > 0) {
      // There are more bytes, so we know this is a newer observation with more bytes
      localObservation.species = reader.readString();
      localObservation.sharedWithProjects = reader.readStringList();
      localObservation.notSharedWithProjects = reader.readStringList();
      localObservation.dateUpdatedInGoogleSheets = reader.readString();
    }


    return localObservation;
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, LocalObservation observation) {
      writer.writeString(observation.uid);
      writer.writeString(observation.observerUid);
      writer.writeDouble(observation.altitudeInMeters);
      writer.writeDouble(observation.longitude);
      writer.writeDouble(observation.latitude);
      writer.writeString(observation.name);
      writer.writeString(observation.location);
      writer.writeString(observation.date);
      writer.writeStringList(observation.signs);
      writer.writeString(observation.pikasDetected);
      writer.writeString(observation.distanceToClosestPika);
      writer.writeString(observation.searchDuration);
      writer.writeString(observation.talusArea);
      writer.writeString(observation.temperature);
      writer.writeString(observation.skies);
      writer.writeString(observation.wind);
      writer.writeStringList(observation.otherAnimalsPresent);
      writer.writeString(observation.siteHistory);
      writer.writeString(observation.comments);
      writer.writeStringList(observation.imageUrls);
      writer.writeStringList(observation.audioUrls);
      writer.writeString(observation.species);
      writer.writeStringList(observation.sharedWithProjects);
      writer.writeStringList(observation.notSharedWithProjects);
      writer.writeString(observation.dateUpdatedInGoogleSheets);
  }
}
```